# HTML5 + jQuery + Infinite Scroll

Tags: html, jquery, infinite-scroll

After much research, I have learned that `binding` the `scroll` event to the `$(window)` in the `live` state is not supported. This is fine, but I do have a question or two in regards to the script I am working on.

I have a website that is utilizing the HTML5 jQuery History Plugin (http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/) to load in pages for a fluid user experience since my site has an anchored audio player within it.

On one of my pages I have created an infinite scroll to load in Albums upon the window scroll. It works fine if you go to the page directly, but if you go there via an HTML5 enabled link (I have some links that are specifically for the HTML5 implementation) it doesn't work.

Here is my Infinite Scroll Code:

```
jQuery(function() {
                var getMoreMedias, loading, mediaType, nearBottomofPage, page, pendingCall, genreType, url, did_scroll;
              page = 1;
              loading = false;
                // did_scroll = false
              mediaType = $('.breadcrumbs strong').attr('rel');
                genreType = $('.breadcrumbs strong').data('genre-id')

              nearBottomofPage = function() {
                return $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $('#footer').height();
              };

              getMoreMedias = function(page, mediaType) {
                    opts = {
                     lines: 12, //The number of lines to draw
                     length: 7, //The length of each line
                     width: 3, //The line thickness
                     radius: 10, //The radius of the inner circle
                     color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
                     speed: 1, //Rounds per second
                     trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
                     shadow: true //Whether to render a shadow
                    };

                    var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin()

                    $('#loadingMore').append(spinner.el)

                    url = '/top_medias/'
                    url += mediaType

                    if(genreType)
                        url += '/' + genreType

                    url += '?page=' + page

                $.ajax({
                        cache: false,
                  url: url,
                  type: 'get',
                  dataType: 'script',
                  success: function(data) {
                    $('#loadingMore').html('');
                            loading = false
                  },
                        error: function() {
                            $('#loadingMore').html('<p>No more results could be found</p>')
                            loading = false
                        }
                });
              };

            $(window).scroll(function(){
                    did_scroll = true
            })

            setInterval(function(){
                if(did_scroll) {
                    if (loading) return;
                if (nearBottomofPage()) {
                      loading = true;
                      page++;
                        getMoreMedias(page, mediaType)
                        did_scroll = false
                }
                }
            }, 250)
        });
```

Is there any way to take what I have above and make it work if the page is accessed via Ajax (which is what the HTML5 plugin essentially does)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this addresses your problem, but the statement that "it works when browsed but not when Ajax loads it" raised a flag to me - Javascript doesn't execute in Ajax loaded pages, rather you must `eval()` evaluate the Javascript.

What I do when I need this functionality is add a hidden `<div>` containing Javascript (without the `' tag and execute that after loading, e.g. (psuedo code)

```
$.ajax(url, success: function() { eval($('#ajax').html(); });

<div id="ajax" style="display:none"> alert('here'); </div>
```

Comment: Yeah sorry for the odd statement. I know that JS doesn't execute in Ajax loaded pages. You have to run the functionality after the AjaxComplete. Your tip is very helpful, though. Thanks!!

Comment: Did you see if that's the problem? Put in an `alert` or a `console.log` to make sure the script is getting executed.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Matt!! I was able to get it working! The one thing I had to do was change `.html()` to `.text()`, but with your suggestion it works like a charm!